# List of Similar Value from Muliti Array in php

Tags: php, arrays

hi i want to display similar value from array. please tell me how can i show result like in this format....i m wating for solution thanks in advance.. please give me solution..
like :

1. Flipkart
2. Makemytrip
3. Trendin
4. Expedia

here is my array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Promo] => P11757
            [OfferId] => 412
            [Offer Name] => Flipkart

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Promo] => P16508
            [OfferId] => 1236
            [Offer Name] => Flipkart

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Promo] => P17087
            [OfferId] => 647
            [Offer Name] => MakeMyTrip

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [Promo] => P17088
            [OfferId] => 44
            [Offer Name] => Makemytrip

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [Promo] => P17089
            [OfferId] => 44
            [Offer Name] => Makemytrip

        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [Promo] => P17426
            [OfferId] => 140
            [Offer Name] => Trendin

        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [Promo] => P18022
            [OfferId] => 779
            [Offer Name] => Expedia

        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [Promo] => P18442
            [OfferId] => 647
            [Offer Name] => MakeMyTrip            

        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [Promo] => P18443
            [OfferId] => 647
            [Offer Name] => MakeMyTrip

        )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about this:

```
$newArray = array(); //new array to store your list
foreach ($array as $key => $value) //loop through your old array
{
    //check if the value already exist in the new array, if not, add it
    if(!in_array($array[$key]['Offer Name'], $newArray)) 
       $newArray[] = $array[$key]['Offer Name'];
}
print_r($newArray); //print your list
```

Comment: thanks for solution...

Comment: @vlabsolution i am glad my answer helped you

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$arr = array();
foreach($multiarray as $array)
{
     $arr[] = $array["Offer Name"];
}
$result = array_unique($arr);
print_r($result);
?>
```

Where $multiarray is the name of your array.

Comment: both code are working thanks

Comment: great! thank you @vlabsolution